# How can I add a extra column with django table2?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm learning  django and how to use django-table2 app. For now I can display my users in a table on my homepage.
But I can't find a way to add a column with a delete button for each row.

tables.py

```py
class UserListTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ("password", "is_superuser", "is_staff", "is_active", "last_login", "date_joined")
        attrs = {
            'class': 'paleblue',
            'th': {
              'class': 'TEST',
            },
        }
```

view.py

```py
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def home(request):
    table = UserListTable(User.objects.all())
    # Update data when they are sorted
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    if isInGroup(request, 'Student'):
        return render(request, 'main/home_student.html')
    else: 
        return render(request, 'main/home_staff.html', {
            'table': table,
        })
```

template

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Home page - Staff {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
// other code here
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% render_table table %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is it even possible ?
I did read the documentation but perhaps I missed where is it explained.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way myself (not sure at all if it's the best solution or not) :

tables:

```py
class UserListTable(tables.Table):

    delete = tables.LinkColumn(
          'account_delete', 
          args= [A('pk')], 
          attrs= {
            'a': {'class': 'btn'}
          },
          text = 'Delete',

    )
       
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ("password", "is_superuser", "is_staff", "is_active", "last_login", "date_joined")
        attrs = {
            'class': 'paleblue',
            'th': {
              'class': 'TEST',
            },
        }
```

url :

```py
    path('account/delete/<int:pk>/', views.account_delete, name='account_delete')
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution.  I don't see how when the button is clicked it submits a POST or GET to the appropriate route to do a delete. I understand that 'account_delete' will get resolved to the right url, and I see "account_delete" in your link column definition, and that the first arg to LinkColumn.__init__ is "viewname"... is that the key thing that is making it work?

Comment: I haven't done this part yet, but I guess you can handle it in the 'account_delete' view by using a condition like "if request.method == 'POST': do_something"

Comment: If you make a public repo of your code I would love to see (and steal) it.

Comment: I'm not allowed but here is an exemple to use the table with a delete button https://pastebin.com/pP7QxeaQ